# Filter on Collection(Edm.String) type fields in Azure Search

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have an index that has an Collection(Edm.String) type field as below which is facetable and filterable.

[Index definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FBL6E.png)

But when I do a query with the payload as below for filtering:
{
     "count": true,
     "search": "Not able to connect to Azure SQL database",
     "searchFields": "Content,keyphrases",
     "select": "keyphrases",
     "facets": ["Source, sort:count", "SubSource, sort:count"],
     "filter": "keyphrases/any(t: search.in(t, 'sql server database'))",
     "top": 6
}

I see results like this, where keyphrases don’t even have the full value “'sql server database”. Why is this so? How does filter work on collection types in Azure Search? How do I do an exact filter?

```
"value": [
    {
        "@search.score": 0.9469998,
        "keyphrases": [
            "windows azure",
            "sql azure",
            "web application",
            "database",
            "desktop"
        ]
    },
    {
        "@search.score": 0.7976283,
        "keyphrases": [
            "Entity Framework Code",
            "modelBuilder",
            "base tables",
            "SQL Azure",
            "one-to-one mapping",
            "factory",
            "pre",
            "large numbers of tables",
            "partitioned view",
            "simple POCO",
            "typical partitioning",
            "horizontal partitioning strategy",
            "CHECK CONSTRAINTs",
            "gt",
            "EntityName",
            "lt",
            "ToTable",
            "DbContext class",
            "UNION",
            "project",
            "OnModelCreating event",
            "foo",
            "file groups",
            "bar",
            "instance",
            "peform",
            "runtime",
            "database",
            "Fluent API",
            "metadata"
        ]
    },
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`search.in` tests whether the field or collection value is contained in a delimited list of values (as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/query-odata-filter-orderby-syntax)). So this expression:

```
keyphrases/any(t: search.in(t, 'sql server database'))
```

is equivalent to this one (because space is one of the default delimiters of `search.in`):

```
keyphrases/any(t: t eq 'sql' or t eq 'server' or t eq 'database')
```

If you're looking for exactly the phrase 'sql server database' (including case and spacing), then the filter should be:

```
keyphrases/any(t: t eq 'sql server database')
```

Comment: I think this documentation needs to be corrected then: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-filters#text-filter-fundamentals

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. It looks like an abbreviated version of the doc I linked to in my answer, and it's missing some important details (like the fact that the default delimiters are space or comma). I'll make sure it gets fixed.

Comment: Although it is by design, it would be great that search.in could allow the spacing in filter value.

Comment: It can. You can pass whatever delimiter you want as the third parameter.

Comment: Example from the docs: $filter=search.in(name, 'Roach motel|Budget hotel', '|')